# Need help optimizing MySQL query with "not in" join

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, notin

My query is currently taking roughly 3 seconds, which I'm sure can be optimized. I just can't figure out how to optimize it.

My app has a reasonably big `products` table (roughly 500,000 records). Each product can be listed on one of 50 domains (listed in a `domains` table). The links between products and domains are stored in the `domains_products` table (which has approximately 1,400,000 records). The slow query is in my app's admin section, where I need to be able to see products that are NOT listed on any domain.

Stripped to the bare bones with all unrelated joins removed, the query in question is:

```sql
SELECT    `products`.*
FROM      `products`
LEFT JOIN `domains_products`
ON        `domains_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE     `products`.`deleted` = 'N'
AND       `domains_products`.`domain_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY  `products`.`id` ASC
```

In this form, the query takes more than 3 seconds and returns a little over 3,000 products (which is correct). If I remove either `WHERE` clause, the query takes 0.12 seconds (but obviously does not return the correct results).

Both tables use the InnoDB engine. The `products` table has a primary key on the `id` column and an index on the `deleted` column. The `domains_products` table only has a `product_id` and `domain_id` column, the primary key is on both these columns and they both have their own index. All relevant columns are `NOT NULL` columns.

`EXPLAIN` gives me this:

```
id select_type table            type possible_keys key        key_len ref         rows   Extra
1  SIMPLE      products         ref  deleted       deleted    1       const       188616 Using where
1  SIMPLE      domains_products ref  product_id    product_id 4       products.id 1      Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Note that although MySQL has discovered the correct keys, it doesn't actually seem to be using them.

The profiler says this:

```
Status               Time
Starting             62 µs
Checking Permissions 7 µs
Checking Permissions 5 µs
Opening Tables       38 µs
System Lock          13 µs
Init                 37 µs
Optimizing           17 µs
Statistics           1,3 ms
Preparing            25 µs
Executing            5 µs
Sorting Result       5 µs
Sending Data         3,3 s
End                  28 µs
Query End            8 µs
Closing Tables       25 µs
Freeing Items        297 µs
Logging Slow Query   4 µs
Cleaning Up          5 µs
```

Note that it seems to be hanging on `Sending Data`. I've tried replacing the join by a NOT IN:

```sql
SELECT `products`.*
FROM   `products`
WHERE  `products`.`deleted` = 'N'
AND    `product`.`id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `product_id`
    FROM   `domains_products`
)
ORDER BY `products`.`id` ASC
```

This query gives the exact same results, but takes 3.8 seconds.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to optimize this query?

Comment: Re: "Note that although MySQL has discovered the correct keys, it doesn't actually seem to be using them": What makes you say that?

Comment: Have you deleted large portions of the table or done other large edits? Perhaps an [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) will fix the problem.

Comment: @ruakh I'm not an expert at reading the EXPLAIN syntax, but since it's saying "Using where" in the Extra-column, I'm assuming MySQL is not using an index. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @lc. Actually, the entire application was moved to a new server two days ago (from a VPS to a dedicated server). So the entire database is brand new. This query was slow on the old VPS as well, I'd hoped the move would have sped things up.

Comment: @rickdenhaan: I'm not an expert at reading the EXPLAIN output, either, and given the documentation's explanation of `Using where`, I definitely see why you'd interpret it how you do. All I can say is -- I'm pretty confident that the documentation is misleading, and that the `Using where` here is harmless.

Comment: @ruakh Okay, so maybe MySQL is using the index, maybe it isn't. It's still slow on this query ;-)

Comment: Is there a foreign key correlating the two tables, or simply an index?

Comment: @lc There are actual foreign keys in `domains_products`: `domain_id` references `domains`.`id` (on delete/update cascade) and `product_id` references `products`.`id` (on delete/update cascade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the "deleted" column.  I'm guessing that almost all of the items in the products table is marked with "N", making the index on the "deleted" column pretty useless in this case.

One thing you can do is create another table, say deleted_domains_products that would store the product_id (and the domain_id if you want).  Then you create a trigger so every time an entry was deleted from domains_products, it would insert an entry into that table.  Then you'll have a smaller set to query against.  And when you're done, you can truncate that table for the next time, so it should always be pretty quick.

Comment: There are currently 15991 products where `deleted` is "Y" and 487601 products where `deleted` is "N". I'll give your idea a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: Thanks, this (mostly) solved the problem. I added a new table containing just the IDs of the deleted products, and added a trigger on my `products` table to automatically add an ID if a product is set to deleted (and vice versa). This has knocked the query down to a manageable average of 1.5 seconds, which I consider to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the following indexes and then rerun the query:

1. domains_products (product_id, domain_id)
2. products (id, deleted)

Tell us how it goes this

Comment: The primary key for domains_products is on both those columns. I added the index on the products table, the query took 2.9, 3.5 and 3.4 seconds the three times I ran it.

Comment: Yes, these are both composite field indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let me know the time it is taking.

```
SELECT `products`.*
FROM   `products`
WHERE  `products`.`deleted` = 'N'
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM `domains_products` 
               WHERE `domains_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
              );
ORDER BY `products`.`id` ASC
```

Comment: This query takes 0.0015 seconds, but returns incorrect results. If I flip it:

    SELECT `products`.*
    FROM   `products`
    WHERE  `products`.`deleted` = 'N'
    AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM `domains_products`
                       WHERE `domains_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
                      )
    ORDER BY `products`.`id` ASC

it returns the correct results, but takes 4.2 seconds.